# Runnnig remote command form jenkins using PsExec.exe gives handle is invalid error

Tags: jenkins, psexec

I am trying to run a remote command from Jenkins.

I am able to run the command from the agent directly successfully.

[image]

But when I am trying the same command from the Jenkins it gives me below error.

[image]

I found the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213606/using-psexec-exe-in-jenkins-handle-is-invalid).

I tried all the solution provided there but its still not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of running it in command line can you convert it to batch script and run it in `Execute Windows Batch`. Please post your batch script too.

Comment: I tried that too it gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you paste the script? The handler is not recognized, which I suspect is due to a connection issue between `master` , `slave` , `your-remote-host` there are couple of ways to install jenkins `slave` , try out multiple windows slaves which are created with different mechanisms one of them may work.